# Cloning a Bitbucket repository via ssh

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, git-clone

How do I clone a repository from Bitbucket via `ssh` instead of `http`? I already have `git` installed in my local machine (Windows).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

1. Generate an SSH key:
   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your-email-address"`
2. Press Enter key until a randomart image is generated.
3. Log into Bitbucket -> `View profile` -> `Manage account` -> `SSH keys` -> `Add key`
4. Paste the key you have generated in Step 1 in the text box. To get the key, run the following command:
   `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
5. Go to your repository -> `Clone`. Now you can see the SSH url for your repository. Copy it.
6. Clone your repository: `git clone <ssh-url>`

Comment: In step 5, do not forget to change HTTPS to SSH in the dropdown. By default, it shows the https url and not the ssh-url. Cheers!

Comment: To make copying hassle free in Step 4, you may use `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy` instead.

Comment: Step 3 should be:
Log into Bitbucket -> View profile -> Personal settings -> SSH keys -> Add key.

Simple copy and paste this url: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/ssh-keys/

Comment: step 6 Where to I find the ssh-irl of my repository?

Comment: Hello @Madlozoz, you just need to go to your repo, then click on clone and switch from https to ssh inside the pop up

Comment: An important thing to remember if you want to use a custom name for your rsa key, just remeber to add it with ssh-add command

For instance:
1)ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/my_private_key -b 2048
2)ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_private_key
3)git clone <your-ssh-url>